# BCP out binary/BLOB/TEXT data on separate file in Sybase

Tags: sybase, bcp

I want BCP out binary/BLOB/TEXT data on separate file in Sybase. How can i do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only BCP at the Table/View level, so if you wish to separate the two, you'll need to create view(s) that contain the data you wish to see, and BCP out of the Views.

Comment: Thanks Michael ! One more question. Suppose if i have 9 BLOB columns and i want to BCP out these 9 columns in 9 different files, then should i have to create 9 different views ? If yes, then is there any way to do it in a single BCP out operation ?  Also what row separator and col separator i would use in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible to BCP in/out a single BLOB value to an individual file. This requires an extra step to move the BLOB value though a temp table. In my book "Tips, Tricks & Recipes for Sybase ASE" (sypron.nl/ttr), this is described in detail, with ready-to-use scripts.